# Salesforce as an identity provider issue

Tags: salesforce, identity

I want to implement Salesforce as an identity provider. so I have according to deployment guide as below:

1. Register Salesforce account
2. Login Salesforce operation panel
3. Administer -> Domain Management -> My Domain -> Apply for new domain -> Successful -> Deploy to Users -> Done

The deployment description that can find "identity provider" item from Administer list, But I can't found this item... even if I used keyword "identity provider" will not find it.

[Administer List schematic diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlIvh.png)  <- (Please refer this image)

Q. How can i used "identity provider" item in operation panel? or How to insert "identity provider" item in operation list?

Please help me to solve this issue, Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this question would be better asked on [Salesforce Stack Exchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Hi Stibu, Thanks for your reminder.    :)